# Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

Tags: apache, shell, hadoop, hive, hadoop2

Hive shell is getting started but whenever i hit any command in shell, say
**hive>** show databases;

i am getting following error:

**FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient**

My **JPS** is like this:
/apache-hive-2.3.0-bin/conf$ jps
3779 ResourceManager
3540 SecondaryNameNode
3909 NodeManager
3384 DataNode
6856 Jps
3257 NameNode
 am getting this gerror?

My SQL Server is also running. Checked it using **netstat -an|grep 3306**, What could be wrong here?

Struggling for days now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you figured this out or not but here are the steps I took to help me fix this error (note: I wasn't worried about losing my old schema, you may be):

1. Make sure your cluster is shut down properly `stop-dfs.sh, stop-yarn.sh`.
2. Move metadata_db `mv /home/user/metadata_db /home/user/metadata_db.tmp`.
3. Shut down your system and start it up again.
4. Start up your cluster `start-dfs.sh, start-yarn.sh`
5. Reinitialize schema with `$HIVE_HOME/bin/schematool -initSchema -dbType derby`.
6. Start hive `$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive`.

Hope this helps someone.